# SwiftUI animation (animation(_:value:): Newbie question

Tags: animation, swiftui

I am learning SwiftUI animation and I have a Newbie question. The .animation() modifier has been deprecated in iOS 15. For animation to work, 'value' has to change. With my changes to an example, the motion is jerky and not as smooth without 'value'. .animation() is deprecated but still works with a warning.

Am I doing it right?

Example from: https://medium.com/apple-developer-academy-federico-ii/drawings-and-animations-in-swiftui-3a2da460e492

```
struct Example4: View {
    @State private var bounceBall: Bool = false
    @State private var hiddenText: String = "Kick the ball!"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(hiddenText)
            Image("ball")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                // *Original* 
                .animation(Animation.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 90, damping: 1.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
                // *Modified*
                .animation(Animation.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 90, damping: 1.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: bounceBall)
                .offset(y: bounceBall ? -200 : 200)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.bounceBall.toggle()
                    self.hiddenText = ""
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Example 4")
    }
}
```

Comment: `.animation()` is deprecated, and you can't use it soon, maybe in iOS 17 or 18

Comment: @NhatNguyenDuc  Thanks. Yes I understand. That is why I want to know the fix. When I add 'value: bounceBall', the motion is jerky,  From all the discussions I searched, it appears that my change should work. My machine is a little older so it could be HW issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my M1 MacBook Air, I had the jerky motion both ways, whether using the deprecated `.animation()` or the new `.animation(value:)`, and yes, you're using the `value: bounceBall` correctly.

I'm also relatively new to developing, nonetheless I want to throw out an alternative to `.animation()` that will get rid of the warning:

```
Image("ball")
    .resizable()
    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
    .clipShape(Circle())
    .offset(y: bounceBall ? -200 : 200)
    .onTapGesture {
        withAnimation(
            Animation.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 90, damping: 1.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
        ) {
            bounceBall.toggle()
            hiddenText = ""
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a good solution. Thanks!